# Is there any good tutorial for custom keyboard implementation in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, tamil

I need to make a custom keyboard for a regional language "Tamil" and I had to bring in tamil font if the user presses the custom keyboard keys. Is that possible? If so any tutorial or resources available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/amkeyboardnumberpad , it is a simple key board but you can see how it is implemented for a quick start.

This site has really good open source controls for IOS. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Will look upon it. :)

Comment: This just adds a button to the keypad on the iPhone.